# How to read PGM images in Java?

Tags: java, javax.imageio, pgm

I feel like I'm missing something simple here (as usual).

I'm trying to read PGM images using Java. Matlab does it just fine - outputting the image pixels (for example, a small 32x32 image) in Matlab gives me something like this:

```
1 0 11 49 94 118 118 106 95 88 85 96 124 143 142 133
```

My Java reader, however, outputs this:

```
1 0 11 49 94 118 118 106 95 88 85 96 124 65533 65533 65533
```

It seems like pixel values above 127 are filled in with 65533, though it does get some random values incorrect, and even assigns almost the entire bottom row to the value of -1.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
filePath = 'imagepath.pgm';
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

// read the header information ...

int [][] data2D = new int [picWidth] [picHeight];

for (int row = 0; row < picHeight; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < picWidth; col++) {
    data2D[row][col] = bufferedReader.read();
    System.out.print(data2D[row][col] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}

fileInputStream.close();
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Here are the unsigned PGM values:

```
     1     0    11    49    94   118   118   106    95    88    85    96   124   143   142   133
    30    26    29    57    96   122   125   114   102    94    91   101   127   146   145   136
    96    85    70    75   101   128   136   126   111   106   106   112   131   149   153   147
   163   147   114    93    99   120   132   123   110   113   124   129   137   154   166   168
   215   195   149   105    88    99   114   111   106   123   148   158   160   174   191   197
   245   224   173   115    81    82   100   109   117   144   179   194   194   205   222   230
   235   217   170   115    78    78   113   117   100    83    80   212   214   226   244   253
   178   167   135    93    68    78   123   129   106    77    69   202   204   222   244   255
   114   110    92    64    54    81   107   105    83    59    56   182   184   201   222   231
    79    80    71    52    55    97    67    55    41    33    42   184   179   181   185   183
    62    66    65    52    63   115    29    16    12    17    30   209   197   174   150   132
    40    47    52    44    55   109   171   196   188   186   208   229   218   179   136   107
    31    38    44    37    43    89   145   167   158   159   191   223   219   179   133   105
    48    52    56    51    57    91   128   133   117   120   157   196   200   168   128   105
    64    67    70    73    87   114   127   107    79    81   118   159   173   154   123   104
    63    67    73    83   107   132   129    91    54    54    88   130   153   146   123   106
```

The header looks like this:

```
P5
# MatLab PGMWRITE file, saved 27-Jun-2002
16 16
255
```

**Edit #2**

Here's the full output to the proof of concept code below:

```
Skipping unknow token: ""
Skipping unknow token: "1^vvj_XU`|���"
Skipping unknow token: ""
Skipping unknow token: "9`z}rf^[e���`UFKe��~ojjp������r]cx�{nq|������ÕiXcroj{��������sQRdmu��������٪sNNqudSP�����]DN{�jME�����rn\@6QkiS;8�����OPG47aC7)!*�����>BA4?s"
Skipping unknow token: ""
Skipping unknow token: ""
Skipping unknow token: "�Ů��(/4,7m�ļ���ڳ�k"
Skipping unknow token: "&,%+Y������۳�i04839[��ux��Ȩ�i@CFIWrkOQv���{h?CISk��[66X���{j"
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
    at Test.main(Test.java:49)
```

Line 49 referred to in the thrown exception is:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Skipping unknow token: \"%s\"", scan.next()));
```

The problem, I'm sure, has something to do with the fact that these image files consist of both ASCII text/numbers as well as binary image data. But if Java has no problem reading PNGs, why the lack of support for PGMs?

**Edit 3**

Ok, I found an implementation that works...unfortunately, it's deprecated:

```
  filePath = "imagepath.pgm"
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
  StreamTokenizer streamTokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(dis);

  // read header text using StreamTokenizer.nextToken()

  data2D = new int [picWidth] [picHeight];
  for (int row = 0; row < picHeight; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < picWidth; col++) {
      data2D[row][col] = dis.readUnsignedByte();
      System.out.print(data2D[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

According to the Java documentation, the `StreamTokenizer(InputStream)` constructor is deprecated, because the `DataInputStream.readLine()` method does not correctly convert raw bytes to characters. However, it seems to work in this specific case on the header, and obviously works for the ensuing binary image data.

Unfortunately, it's still deprecated, and it seems that by intermixing a `BufferedReader` as the documentation suggests only results in `EOFException`s after reading the header and attempting to use the `DataInputStream` to read the raw bytes. Still looking for a solution...

Comment: Done and done, let me know what else you might need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the wrong class to read raw data from the file. As the `BufferedReader` documentation says:

> `public int read() throws IOException`
>
> Reads a single character.
>
> Returns: The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

So each call to the `read()` method of `BufferedReader` actually consumes one or two bytes (based on character encoding) from the input stream, which is not what you want. This also explains why you get a lot of -1: the stream ended much earlier than you thought.

Since PGM contains values as ASCII decimal, it is easy to parse using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Here's an *almost untested* code that shows how to read a PGM image assuming that:

- it contains a single comment after the magic number (i.e. it does not have lines that start with a # except the second one)
- the PGM file is exactly 4 lines long.

Here's the code:

```
String filePath = "image.pgm";
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
// Discard the magic number
scan.nextLine();
// Discard the comment line
scan.nextLine();
// Read pic width, height and max value
int picWidth = scan.nextInt();
int picHeight = scan.nextInt();
int maxvalue = scan.nextInt();

fileInputStream.close();
            
 // Now parse the file as binary data
 fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
 
 // look for 4 lines (i.e.: the header) and discard them
 int numnewlines = 4;
 while (numnewlines > 0) {
     char c;
     do {
         c = (char)(dis.readUnsignedByte());
     } while (c != '\n');
     numnewlines--;
 }

 // read the image data
 int[][] data2D = new int[picHeight][picWidth];
 for (int row = 0; row < picHeight; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col < picWidth; col++) {
         data2D[row][col] = dis.readUnsignedByte();
         System.out.print(data2D[row][col] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

Need to implement: support for comment lines, values for each element should be divided by `maxvalue`, error checking for malformed files, exception handling. I tested it on a PGM file using UNIX end-of-lines, but it should work on Windows too.

Let me stress that **this is not a robust nor complete implementation of a PGM parser**. This code is intended just as proof of concept that maybe accomplishes just enough for your needs.

If you really need a robust PGM parser, you may use the tools provided by [Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This works well, but it gives rise to a new problem: parsing out the header file. I used a BufferedReader/StreamTokenizer to read the header characters, and for some reason once that's complete, the first call to dis.readByte() throws a EOFException. If I remove the header from the file and just read straight from the binary, I run into a different problem: the first 55 bytes it reads are junk numbers; the 56th byte is the "1" that shows up first in my original post, followed by all the corresponding numbers (up to 55 bytes short, due to the junk lead-in). Any thoughts?

Comment: Er sorry, disregard the bit about the 55 bytes; it works just fine if I eliminate the header (and hence, the BufferedReader/StreamTokenizer and have a single file handle - the DataInputStream - reading from the file).

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the PGM file format specification. I'll try to give it a shot in a few minutes.

Comment: I modified the code snippet, now it works with your sample PGM file.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having problems: I get an InputMismatchException when I try to run your new code. It reads the header lines correctly, but on its first run through both loops in reading the binary image data, it throws the exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: You get that exception because the Scanner expected a token representing a integer but found "something else". I added a small check that prints on stdout the unexpected token. To understand why you get that exception you should debug the code and see what token the scanner expected (probably a string representing an integer, since you say that it correctly parses the header) and what you get instead.

Comment: I posted the full output to your code; I don't know if you did this, but the "image data" I posted of all the pixel values is what the reader *should* pick up and output. What's actually stored in the file is binary image data, not ASCII integer values. The values I posted are what Matlab reads when it opens a PGM file, and what I would like to be able to read from within Java. Thanks for all your help so far; hopefully we can nail this!

Comment: Posted another update; found a deprecated method that seems to work, but unfortunately, it's deprecated :P

Comment: Modified again the code so that it reads the PGM header using a Scanner, then reads the image data using a DataInputStream. This is not the fastest or cleanest way to parse a PGM file, but it is extremely easy to see what's going on.