# Java Image Processing using PGM files and Multi-Dimensional arrays

Tags: java, methods, pgm

I'm in a intro CS class. We've been given a project where we've been supplied a basic file, and a few .PGM files of our school's mascot and things like that. Basically we're told that we need to use the framework they've written, and flip, rotate etc.. this file.

How do you flip or rotate clockwise a PGM file? I'm totally lost as what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this question useful [How to read PGM images in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639198/how-to-read-pgm-images-in-java) . You could use this to read into a 2D array. It should be fairly easy to rotate this by 90, 180 or -90 degrees (any other value will be a lot of work with interpolation).

The flip and rotate operations involving interchanging x and y values and/or changing the signs. [This](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~smx/IVIPracticals/exercise1.html) has some examples.