# How to make plots in Java like in Matlab (same syntax)

Tags: java, matlab, plot, jfreechart

Plotting in Matlab is very easy and straightforward. For example:

```
figure('Position_',[100,80,1000,600])         
plot(x,y1,'-.or','MarkerSize',0.2,'MarkerFaceColor','r','LineWidth',2)
xlabel('Matrix1')
ylabel('Matrix2')
grid on 
hold on
axis([-1,1,0,var1*1.2])
plot(x,y2,'-k','MarkerSize',0.5,'MarkerFaceColor','k','LineWidth',4)
title('My plot')
figuresdir = 'dir'; 
saveas(gcf,strcat(figuresdir, 'plotimage'), 'bmp');
```

I found, however, that plotting in Java is more difficult and I have to use packages like [JMathPlot](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPu_fShL7OAhVJSRoKHcUFD10QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fyannrichet%2Fjmathplot&usg=AFQjCNF7K6ikbuyNFsszSr7ItsLiFr4Q4w&sig2=sH0sRU23ekO2dlm8Qo-5Kw) or [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). However, I find it difficult to merge plots and print them to a file using these packages.

Is there an easy way to make plots in Java that uses (about) the same syntax as Matlab does?

Comment: Would you be interested in invoking Matlab from Java? I can give an example of that

Comment: No, i can't call matlab from java because the end user can't have matlab installed on his pc

Comment: I have answered your question. See below ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, Matlab is designed specifically to make things such as plotting as easy as possible. Other languages simply don't have the same kind of support for quick-and-easy plots.

Therefore I decided to write a little Matlab-style charting class based on [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), just for you:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYTitleAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.block.BlockBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.title.LegendTitle;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleAnchor;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;


public class MatlabChart {

    Font font;
    JFreeChart chart;
    LegendTitle legend;
    ArrayList<Color> colors;
    ArrayList<Stroke> strokes;
    XYSeriesCollection dataset;

    public MatlabChart() {
        font = JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT;
        colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
        strokes = new ArrayList<Stroke>();
        dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    }

    public void plot(double[] x, double[] y, String spec, float lineWidth, String title) {
        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries(title);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            series.add(x[i],y[i]);
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        FindColor(spec,lineWidth);
    }

    public void RenderPlot() {
        // Create chart
        JFreeChart chart = null;
        if (dataset != null && dataset.getSeriesCount() > 0)
            chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(null,null,null,dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true, false, false);
        else
            System.out.println(" [!] First create a chart and add data to it. The plot is empty now!");
        // Add customization options to chart
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(i, colors.get(i));
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(i, strokes.get(i));
        }
        ((NumberAxis)plot.getDomainAxis()).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        ((NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis()).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        legend = chart.getLegend();
        chart.removeLegend();
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    public void CheckExists() {
        if (chart == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First plot something in the chart before you modify it.");
        }
    }

    public void font(String name, int fontSize) {
        CheckExists();
        font = new Font(name, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        chart.getTitle().setFont(font);
        chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(font);
        chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(font);
        chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(font);
        chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(font);
        legend.setItemFont(font);
    }

    public void title(String title) {
        CheckExists();
        chart.setTitle(title);
    }

    public void xlim(double l, double u) {
        CheckExists();
        chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setRange(l, u);
    }

    public void ylim(double l, double u) {
        CheckExists();
        chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setRange(l, u);
    }

    public void xlabel(String label) {
        CheckExists();
        chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setLabel(label);
    }

    public void ylabel(String label) {
        CheckExists();
        chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setLabel(label);
    }

    public void legend(String position) {
        CheckExists();
        legend.setItemFont(font);
        legend.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        legend.setFrame(new BlockBorder(Color.BLACK));
        if (position.toLowerCase().equals("northoutside")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
            chart.addLegend(legend);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("eastoutside")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
            chart.addLegend(legend);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("southoutside")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
            chart.addLegend(legend);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("westoutside")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.LEFT);
            chart.addLegend(legend);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("north")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.50,0.98,legend,RectangleAnchor.TOP);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("northeast")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.98,0.98,legend,RectangleAnchor.TOP_RIGHT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("east")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.98,0.50,legend,RectangleAnchor.RIGHT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("southeast")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.98,0.02,legend,RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("south")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.50,0.02,legend,RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("southwest")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.02,0.02,legend,RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("west")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.LEFT);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.02,0.50,legend,RectangleAnchor.LEFT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        } else if (position.toLowerCase().equals("northwest")) {
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
            XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.02,0.98,legend,RectangleAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
            chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(ta);
        }
    }

    public void grid(String xAxis, String yAxis) {
        CheckExists();
        if (xAxis.equalsIgnoreCase("on")){
            chart.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
            chart.getXYPlot().setDomainMinorGridlinesVisible(true);
            chart.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            chart.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
            chart.getXYPlot().setDomainMinorGridlinesVisible(false);
        }
        if (yAxis.equalsIgnoreCase("on")){
            chart.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
            chart.getXYPlot().setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible(true);
            chart.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            chart.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
            chart.getXYPlot().setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void saveas(String fileName, int width, int height) {
        CheckExists();
        File file = new File(fileName); 
        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(file,this.chart,width,height);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

    public void FindColor(String spec, float lineWidth) {
        float dash[] = {5.0f};
        float dot[] = {lineWidth};
        Color color = Color.RED;                    // Default color is red
        Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(lineWidth); // Default stroke is line   
        if (spec.contains("-"))
            stroke = new BasicStroke(lineWidth);
        else if (spec.contains(":"))
            stroke = new BasicStroke(lineWidth, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, dash, 0.0f);
        else if (spec.contains("."))
            stroke = new BasicStroke(lineWidth, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 2.0f, dot, 0.0f);
        if (spec.contains("y"))
            color = Color.YELLOW;
        else if (spec.contains("m"))
            color = Color.MAGENTA;
        else if (spec.contains("c"))
            color = Color.CYAN;
        else if (spec.contains("r"))
            color = Color.RED;
        else if (spec.contains("g"))
            color = Color.GREEN;
        else if (spec.contains("b"))
            color = Color.BLUE;
        else if (spec.contains("k"))
            color = Color.BLACK;
        colors.add(color);
        strokes.add(stroke);
    }
}
```

With this, you can plot in Java with syntax very close to Matlab:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create some sample data
        double[] x = new double[100]; x[0] = 1;
        double[] y1 = new double[100]; y1[0] = 200;
        double[] y2 = new double[100]; y2[0] = 300;
        for(int i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
            x[i] = i+1; 
            y1[i] = y1[i-1] + Math.random()*10 - 4;
            y2[i] = y2[i-1] + Math.random()*10 - 6;
        }

        // JAVA:                             // MATLAB:
        MatlabChart fig = new MatlabChart(); // figure('Position',[100 100 640 480]);
        fig.plot(x, y1, "-r", 2.0f, "AAPL"); // plot(x,y1,'-r','LineWidth',2);
        fig.plot(x, y2, ":k", 3.0f, "BAC");  // plot(x,y2,':k','LineWidth',3);
        fig.RenderPlot();                    // First render plot before modifying
        fig.title("Stock 1 vs. Stock 2");    // title('Stock 1 vs. Stock 2');
        fig.xlim(10, 100);                   // xlim([10 100]);
        fig.ylim(200, 300);                  // ylim([200 300]);
        fig.xlabel("Days");                  // xlabel('Days');
        fig.ylabel("Price");                 // ylabel('Price');
        fig.grid("on","on");                 // grid on;
        fig.legend("northeast");             // legend('AAPL','BAC','Location','northeast')
        fig.font("Helvetica",15);            // .. 'FontName','Helvetica','FontSize',15
        fig.saveas("MyPlot.jpeg",640,480);   // saveas(gcf,'MyPlot','jpeg');
    }
}
```

Now we can compare the final JFreeChart figure to same Matlab figure that we get from this code:

```
figure('Position',[100 100 640 480]); hold all;
plot(x,y1,'-r','LineWidth',2);
plot(x,y2,':k','LineWidth',3);
title('Stock 1 vs. Stock 2');
xlim([10 100]);
ylim([200 300]);
xlabel('Days');
ylabel('Price');
grid on;
legend('AAPL','BAC','Location','northeast');
saveas(gcf,'MyPlot','jpeg');
```

**Result Java** (with the MatlabChart() class):

[image]

**Result Matlab:**

[image: JFreeChart plot demo]

The `MatlabChart()` class I wrote has support for some of the basic plotting syntax in Matlab. You can indicate line styles (`:`,`-`,`.`), change line colors (`y`,`m`,`c`,`r`,`g`,`b`,`w`,`k`), change the `LineWidth` and change the position of the legend (`northoutside`,`eastoutside`,`soutoutside`, `westoutside`,`north`,`east`,`south`,`west`,`northeast`,`southeast`,`southwest`,`northwest`). You can also turn the `grid` on for the x and y-axis independently. For example: `grid("off","on");` turns the x-axis grid `off` and turns the y-axis grid `on`.

That should make plotting in Java a lot easier for those used to plotting in Matlab :)

Comment: @JackTurky Glad to help you out! You can also create other charts than just the `XYLineChart`. You can take a look at the [ChartFactory](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) for the other chart types.